# Layout of a simple PHP form needs altering

Tags: php, html, css, forms, concrete5

I'm trying to create a simple inline form that displays an entry field followed by a submit button - how can I alter this existing code so that these elements display horizontally in one row? ...I've tried altering the form class but no success. Thank you in advance.

PHP

```
<div class="d3-mailchimp" data-block-id="<?php echo $bID; ?>">
<?php 
if (isset($errors)) {
    $errors->output();
}

if (isset($message)) {
    echo '<p class="message">'.$message.'</p>';
} else {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $this->action('submit') ?>" onsubmit="d3_mailchimp_submit(this); return false;">
        <?php $token->output('d3_mailchimp.subscribe'); ?>

        <div class="form-group field">
            <?php    
            echo $form->email('email_address', '', [
                'required' => 'required',
                'placeholder' => t(''),
            ]);
            ?>
        </div>

        <?php
        if ($showTermsCheckbox) {
            ?>
            <div class="accept-terms">
                <label for="accept_terms">
                    <?php
                    echo $form->checkbox('accept_terms', 1, 0, [
                        'required' => 'required',
                    ]);
                    ?>
                    <?php echo $acceptTermsText; ?>
                </label>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

        <div class="submit-button">
            <?php 
            echo $form->submit('submit', t('Subscribe'), [
                'class' => 'button',
            ]);
            ?>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php    
}
?>
```

Comment: You have two fields - "email" and "accept terms", and then a button. You want all of those laid out horizontally in one row, is that right? Also, you'll need to show us the relevant CSS classes so we know how they affect your divs.

Comment: P.S. what does this have to do with mailchimp? This seems primarily a HTML and CSS question - I suggest you add those tags, and remove any which aren't actually directly relevant to the question. Then your question is more likely to be seen by people with relevant expertise to help with your layout issue.

Comment: @ADyson thank you -  yes I want to display elements horizontally in one row.

Comment: ok so please provide the CSS information I requested. CSS plays an important role in determining the final layout, as well as the HTML.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson - Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to provide the exact CSS information that you would require. Are you able to quickly inspect it on my site? I've placed a copy of the form just before the page footer at: https://www.collierhomes.com.au/typography

Comment: Go to your CSS file and, at, minimum, find the css classes which are being applied to your divs in the HTML you've shown. And also anything which is applied to the form itself. Do you understand how to use CSS?

Comment: Either that or use the browser's element inspector to find what classes are being applied to those elements, it will give you the rules too, and where they come from

Comment: BTW to be honest the quickest way to do what you're asking is probably to remove all the `<div` elements inside the `<form`. But whether it will produce a nicely spaced layout I don't know, you'd have to try. But why do you care really? Your site looks nicely presented as it is, and it will be responsive on screens where there isn't enough width to display everything horizontal anyway - you can't consider only desktop users with widescreen monitors in your design.